# StatusBar preferences not working: phonegap version 3.6.3

Tags: ios, cordova, config, statusbar

I have a problem with the StatusBar in iOS. My app ID is 234560, StatusBar version "0.1.4" as suggested ([here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/715)) and phonegap version 3.6.3. I have granted the permissions (CDVStatusBar) and the preferences (StatusBarOverlaysWebView false, StatusBarBackgroundColor A7A7A7 and StatusBarStyle lightcontent) with no sucess. My bar still appears as if StatusBarOverlaysWebView would be set to true and the background color is also not applied. This is how the relevant preferences are set in my config.xml:

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
<preference name="orientation" value="both" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<feature name="Device">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature>
<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#A7A7A7"/>
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

I would love to have any assistance, I have been reading a lot of issues regarding to this topic but non of them were ussing this phonegap version. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I decided to remove the plugin and then add it again, it worked!!

Comment: Thanks @sami-andoni, what do you mean by deleting the plugin? From config.xml?

Comment: You have to add the status bar plugin for the preferences to work, I did it via CLI 'cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar', then removed it with 'cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.statusbar' and added it again when it hanged

Answer (score 0):

The [github site](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) for the plugin says this which worked for me:

## iOS Quirks:

Starting with iOS 11 you must include viewport-fit=cover in your index.html viewport meta tag if you want the status bar to overlay the webview:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, **viewport-fit=cover**">`